# Handle multiple buttons using one form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with different text fields and some buttons. I want for every press of a button to execute a different operations, but using the the same function of ng-submit(). For example I want to implement CRUD operations on a database, and based on the data I get from the form to execute another operations. Based on the information from another post from the site I managed to do this:

```
<form name="formUser" ng-submit="cruduser()" role="form">
    // I didn't put the text fields because are irrelevant for this problem
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="addButton=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="readButton=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Read</button>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="updateButton=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Update</button>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="deleteButton=true" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my .js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('admin')
    .controller('AdminController',
        ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AdminService',
            function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AdminService) {

                $scope.cruduser = function() {
                    this.addButton  = false;
                    this.readButton = false;
                    this.updateButton = false;
                    this.deleteButton = false;

                    if(this.addButton) {
                        console.log('Add');
                    }

                    if(this.readButton) {
                        console.log('Read');
                    }

                    if(this.updateButton) {
                        console.log('Update');
                    }

                    if(this.deleteButton) {
                        console.log('Delete');
                    }
                };


                $scope.redirect = function() {
                    session.sessionValue = ' ';
                    window.location = "/#/login";
                }
            }]);
```

The problem is that after I initialize the buttons with "false", they remain stuck with that value.

Comment: I don't know why you are reseting `this.addButton = true;` inside of your function, but you could pass parameters in it with: `ng-click="cruduser('add')"`, and receive with: `$scope.cruduser = function(action) {`. Then it's enough to check what you want to do with: `if(action=="add"){...}`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey this.addButton was supposed to be false, but I modified the code and I forgot about it. I will try with the solution you provided. Be right back.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey It works, thank you very much. You should put it as answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the type of operation that you want in your `cruduser`function on click of the buttons like this:

```
<button ng-click = "cruduser('add')"></button>
```

Then in the `cruduser` function in the controller you can check for the passed operation like this:

```
 $scope.cruduser = function(crudOp) {
     if (crudOp === 'add') {
//do something
  }
}
```